# Eigen: inverting rectangular matrix (least norm solution)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3, matrix-inverse

I have very simple question but unfortunately i cannot find answer in Eigen documentation

I have a "fat" matrix **A** (number of rows is less than number of cols) and i want to find least norm pseudoinverse of this matrix.

Ideally i want to find it via least norm **QR** decomposition as specified in [this](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/08-min-norm.pdf) slides.

According slides i can use straight-forward approach to do this by using this formula

```
A.transpose() * (A * A.transpose()).inverse()
```

But i hope that there is more elegant solution in Eigen

PS Sorry for my English

Comment: Do you need the actual (pseudo) inverse, or do you just want to solve equations?

Comment: @chtz i need inverse. Components of this matrix will be used further in big least squares problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is full rank then your formula is correct and you can also obtain it from the `HouseholderQR` decomposition of `A.transpose()`:

```
MatrixXd A(3,6);
A.setRandom();
HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A.transpose());
MatrixXd pinv;
pinv.setIdentity(A.cols(), A.rows());
pinv = qr.householderQ() * pinv;
pinv = qr.matrixQR().topLeftCorner(A.rows(),A.rows()).triangularView<Upper>().transpose().solve<OnTheRight>(pinv);
```

If not, then you'll have to use [Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition.html) that is much simpler to use because it's main purpose is to solve minimal-norm problems:

```
CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition<MatrixXd> cqr(A);
pinv = cqr.pseudoInverse();
```